# Importing a project from clearcase source control to RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I'm attempting to import a clearcase project into rtc source control and I'm following this tutorial :

[https://jazz.net/library/article/50](http://Using%20the%20ClearCase%20Importer%20to%20Import%20ClearCase%20History)

Is this tutorial sufficient ? When code is checked into clearcase will it also be checked into rtc source control automatically?

Any common pitfalls / online tutorials welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, for a couple of baselines, I simply create an import RTC stream (ie, a stream dedicated for imports), and I manually copy a few baselines, selected from a dynamic view (which has a config spec you can easily change in order to select the appropriate baseline)

Whatever the tool you end up using for this import, the common pitfalls are:

- import directly in an RTC Stream used for development: it is best to isolate the import in a dedicated Stream, which will allow you to start working on one of the imported baselines in an RTC Dev Stream, while completing further round of import later in time in the Import Stream.
- import *all* the history (instead of only a few selected baselines)
- import without cleaning first (ie you might realize you stored in ClearCase quite a few binaries, libraries or other generated files that you might want to ignore, through a `.jazzignore` file for the import)
- import without refactoring the components: a UCM ClearCase component might have been use over the year as one giant bucket for multiple projects codebases.
  The import to another VCS is the good time to split it into several smaller components.
- Shutting down ClearCase completely after the import: since you don't import all the history and not all the owner for each versions, you might need to consult back from time to time the history stored in ClearCase.
  Don't forget to lock the vobs though, to ensure a read-only access.